# Draw route between my current location and a given marker in map fragment android

Tags: android, google-maps, android-fragments

In my app I want to draw a route between a selected marker displayed in my map and my current location.

I am working with fragments and it is a little bit confusing; I can't find any method that returns the current location in a fragment. I've searched for two days with no result. My map works with markers, but I don't know the right method that works with fragments.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to get current location out of Android map v2 - is to use [GoogleMap#getMyLocation()](http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/GoogleMap.html#getMyLocation%28%29) interface (**EDIT** - just noticed it is deprecated already:)). If this is not enough for you - there is more complex and flexible way - http://developer.android.com/training/location/retrieve-current.html

Drawing path between your current location and specified marker is simple as well. Just look at the [GoogleMap.addPolyline()](http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/GoogleMap.html#addPolyline%28com.google.android.gms.maps.model.PolylineOptions%29) interface.

Comment: when I use googleMap.getMyLocation the map crashs and it is returning null pointer exception in my logcat plz tell me what's causing this,thx

Comment: map is not initialized?

Comment: No it is initialized now it is working fine but it doesn't zoom to my current location